# django serialize a model in desired way for api

Tags: python, json, django

I have a model `Staff` which consists simple staff information.

And I have another model `Schedule` with schedule information

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    staff = models.ForeignKey(Staff, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    attendance = models.DateTimeField()
```

I am getting the schedule by date something like

```
schedules = Schedule.objects.filter(attendance__date=today)
```

Now I want to return json of it for the api. Currently I am doing

```
raw_data = serializers.serialize("python", schedules)
return JsonResponse(raw_data, safe=False)
```

It is giving me response something like:

```
`
[
  {
    model: "schedule.schedule",
    pk: 11,
    fields: {
      staff: 1,
      attendance: "some_date",
    }
  }

]
```

`

But I want the json to be without model name and instead of ID on foreign key I want user information and id instead of foreign key.

```
`
[
  {
    id: 11,
    fields: {
      staff: {
        id: 6,
        name: 'Jack'
      },
      attendance: 'some_date',
    }
  }

]
`
```

Can I get this from serializer of I have to make a custom dictionary and add all the field in my design and dump it ?

Help will be much appriciated :)

Comment: You should use Django REST Framework which allows you to define custom serialisers.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you for the response. That will be great to use DRF but what if I dont want to use that ? What will be the good approach ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as a suggestion, I think you should check out [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). DRF provides comprehensive and pretty good API for building a REST API. Otherwise, you'll end up reinventing the wheel most of the time.

As answer to your actual question, you need to get relevant row (or rows) from database and serialize yourself before returning in a `JsonResponse`. An example would be like this (note that since I don't know your `Staff` model's fields, I assumed it has a field called `name`):

```
from django.http import JsonResponse


class Schedule(models.Model):
    staff = models.ForeignKey(Staff, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    attendance = models.DateTimeField()


schedules = Schedule.objects.select_related('staff')

serialized_schedules = []

for schedule in schedules:
    serialized_schedules.append({
        'id': schedule.pk,
        'fields': {
            'staff': {
                'id': schedule.staff.id,
                'name': schedule.staff.name,
            },
            'attendance': schedule.attendance,
        },
    })

return JsonResponse(serialized_schedules, safe=False)
```